# Is it possible to pass two form name in on "formValueSelector" Redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have created a forum section and want to use it with two different forms. My problem is can we pass two form name to "formValueSelector"

I have two forms name `a` and `b`

and curruntly I am able to pass only one name at a time like :

```
const selector = formValueSelector("a"); 

export default connect((state) => {
  const { phone_number } = selector(state, "c") || {};

})(c);
```

is it possible to pass two form name to formValueSelector in one component or I need to create separate to use with `b`

PS: I want to use `{ phone_number }` in separate form components

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/), for arguments:

> form : String [required]
>   The name of the form you are connecting to. Must be the same as the form config value you gave to reduxForm().

There are no other ways to call `formValueSelector`. Simply use 2 selectors:

```
const formASelector = formValueSelector("a"); 
const formBSelector = formValueSelector("b"); 

export default connect((state) => {
  const { phone_number } = formASelector(state, "c") || {};
  const { first_name } = formBSelector(state, "d") || {};

})(c);
```

Comment: can I use `const {  phone_number } = formBSelector(state, "c") || {};`

Comment: I want to use `{ phone_number }`in separate form components

Comment: I'm confused. Form state is in one place. If you have 2 separate components, just use the form selector in each component.